When using kubectl behind a proxy, can I set an environment variable to provide a custom certificate authority?
I need to use kubectl behind a HTTP proxy. Kubectl gives an error "certificate signed by unknown authority". This goes away if I do kubectl --insecure-skip-tls-verify but I'd rather install the CA for my proxy in a way that kubectl knows to trust it. Is there an environment variable I can set with a path to my CA that will cause kubectl to trust the CA? I'm looking for the equivalent of CURL_CA_BUNDLE for curl, which works like this:
CURL_CA_BUNDLE=path/to/ca.crt curl https://example.com

I'm aware that I edit my kubeconfig like this:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: path/to/ca.crt

but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this with an environment variables.

Another workaround that might work is to set your SSL_CERT_FILE environment to point the path of your CA certificate. If you are behind an HTTP proxy you'll also likely need to configure the proxy environment variables.
export SSL\_CERT\_FILE=path/to/ca.crt
export HTTP\_PROXY=http://your.proxy.:port
export HTTPS\_PROXY=https://your.proxy.:port
Otherwise, you can just simply edit your config to trust the CA see this Proxy reference.

Proxy

kubectl config set proxy

kubectl does not work when I set HTTPS_PROXY


